# A fixed size div/span that goes with the document flow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an iOS-style toggle switch in HTML/CSS/JavaScript. It's at the point that I'm mostly pleased with the result. I am having a lot of trouble making it work as an element that can be inlined with other content though. If I make the container element a span, the structure of the contents "falls apart". Any attempts to restore that (e.g. display: block) fix the content, but break the flow again.

Current version is [here](http://azureblue.org/so/slider.html), and reproduced below. All resources (mootools and an image for the handle) are online and linked absolutely, should you feel the urge to experiment with any fixes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Slider experiment</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.1/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">

        .slider {
            border                  : thin solid #808080;
            display                 : block;
            width                   : 90px;
            overflow                : hidden;
            font-family             : sans-serif;
            font-size               : 80%;
            margin                  : 10px;

            cursor                  : pointer;      /* We don't want the text selection cursor here  */

            -moz-border-radius      : 3px;
            -webkit-border-radius   : 3px;
            -khtml-border-radius    : 3px;
            border-radius           : 3px;

            opacity                 : 0.99;         /* Completely transparent isn't clickable in Firefox */
        }

        .slider div {
            width                   : 200px;        /* More than enough for contents, to avoid wrapping */
            display                 : block;

            position                : relative;     /* So that the z-index has an effect */
            z-index                 : -1;

        }

        .slider div span {
            text-align              : center;
            line-height             : 19px;
            padding-top             : 1px;
            height                  : 19px;
            float                   : left;
            width                   : 62px;
            font-weight             : bold;

            -moz-border-radius      : 2px;
            -webkit-border-radius   : 2px;
            -khtml-border-radius    : 2px;
            border-radius           : 2px;

        }


        .slider div span.tab {
            padding-top             : 0px;
            width                   : 32px;
            margin-left             : -3px;
            margin-right            : -3px;

            position                : relative;     /* So that the z-index has an effect */
            z-index                 : 0;
        }

        .slider div span.on {
            background-color        : #4040ff;
            color                   : #E0E0E0;
        }

        .slider div span.off {
            background-color        : #E0E0E0;
            color                   : #a0a0a0;
        }

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
            function switchOff(itm)
            {
                console.log("Switching off");
                itm.fx.start('-60px');
                itm.state = 0;
            }

            function switchOn(itm)
            {
                console.log("Switching on");
                itm.fx.start('0px');
                itm.state = 1;
            }

            window.addEvent('domready', function() {

                $$('.slider').each( function(itm) {

                    itm.fx = new Fx.Tween(itm.getChildren()[0], {duration: '125', property: 'margin-left'});
                    itm.state = 1;
                    itm.addEvent('click', function() {
                        if (itm.state==1)
                        {
                            switchOff(itm);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            switchOn(itm);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

        //-->
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 400px; margin: 10px">
            Switch :
            <div class="slider">
                <div><span class="on">ONLINE</span><span class="tab"><img src="http://azureblue.org/so/handle.png" width=32px height=20px></span><span class="off">OFFLINE</span></div>
            </div>

            <div class="slider">
                <div><span class="on">ON</span><span class="tab"><img src="http://azureblue.org/so/handle.png" width=32px height=20px></span><span class="off">OFF</span></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I'd really like to be able to do is have the option of placing the control anywhere in the flow, so I could have two side by side if I wanted, or on consecutive lines.

(yes, it should be a proper Mootools class - that's the next job!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `display: inline-block`.

You would still have the block properties, width, height, padding, margin properties, but still easy to display in inline layout (i.e. form, or some other layout.)

Comment: Works from IE8, but IE6/7 also accept it on naturally inline elements. [QuirksMode - display compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

Comment: You'll also have to get rid of white-space if you want this to live side-by-side without white-space (http://www.impressivewebs.com/inline-block/). And the web penetration rates for IE6/IE7 make it so I'm shocked anyone considers supporting it. 2 versions and below is best.

Comment: I wasn't aware of 'inline-block' as an option, but that does exactly what I wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the CSS and try **float:left**

Comment: Floating requires extra management of the other content to get the intended layout.